# XCTEST addUIInterruptionMonitor false selects cancel button

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode10, xctestcase

I have multiple system alerts that appear one after another and I handle them using addUIInterruptionMonitor.  The last alert I would like to not interact with but if you return false from addUIInterruptionMonitor it will automatically select the 'cancel' button (or if there is only one button it will select that button).  Is there a way to say 'do nothing' when you catch an alert using addUIInterruptionMonitor?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Returning `false` from the interruption monitor's handler indicates that the interruption has not been handled yet, and the system will handle it for you if none of your registered interruption monitors handle it.

To do nothing with the alert, you could return `true` instead, indicating that you have handled the interruption yourself, or execute your assertion - or whatever code you would like to execute while the alert is still present - within the interruption monitor's handler.

Comment: Returning true does not work. The tests fails and I can see the console saying: Checking `Expect predicate `exists == 0` for object Alert` and then it fails. It never makes it back to the code outside of the handler block.